# Creating a `SecondaryMap` with default values in Rust

Tags: rust

Given a `SlotMap`, can one create a `SecondaryMap` that maps each key from the `SlotMap` into a default value?

We can create a function like so:

```rust
fn create_secondary_map<K, I, V>(slotmap: SlotMap<K, I>, val: V) -> SecondaryMap<K, V> {
    let map = SecondaryMap::new();
    for key in slotmap.keys() {
        map.insert(key, val);
    }
    map
}
```

But I would prefer to use a more "native" way to do the conversion, maybe using a method that exists already. I didn't manage to find anything that creates another `SecondaryMap` that is filled already, does anyone know about such a thing?

I want to use it like so:

```rust
let secondary = slotmap.create_secondary(def_value);
```

Where maybe `def_value` will be a closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for a dedicated method when the standard iterator mechanisms are available and more composable. Try something like this:

```
use slotmap::{Key, SecondaryMap, SlotMap};

fn create_secondary_map<K, I, V>(slotmap: &SlotMap<K, I>, val: V) -> SecondaryMap<K, V>
where
    K: Key,
    V: Clone,
{
    slotmap.keys().map(|key| (key, val.clone())).collect()
}
```